# Присвоить параметру функции класса значение по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Есть объект класса A, в нем есть переменная a со значением ноль. Возможно ли присвоить это значение параметру функции func по умолчанию? Примерный вариант:

```
struct A{
    int a = 0;
    int func(int a = a){
        return a;
    }
    
};
```

Comment: Вот если бы `a` был `static int a`...

Comment: @Harry а всякие const/constexpr?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Главное - чтоб к нему можно было обратиться без `this`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, так нельзя делать. Только если так:

```cpp
struct A {
    int a = 0;

    int func() {
        return func(a);
    }

    int func(int a) {
        return a;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    static constexpr int a = 0;
    int func(int a = a) {
        return a;
    }  
};

int main() {
    std::cout << A{}.func() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Решением не является - в условии `a` - член объекта, а не класса.

Comment: @Mikhailo не понял, "Есть класс A, в нем есть переменная a со значением ноль"

Comment: `struct A{
    int a = 0;` Из кода очевидно, что имелся в виду не статический член.

Comment: @Mikhailo чтобы можно было его сделать значением по умолчанию, надо сделать его статическим, что я и показал в ответе. Тем более там написано "Примерный вариант" и ориентироваться на код, как на неизменяемый, а не на текстовое условие задачи, странно

Comment: Это моя ошибка. Речь, конечно, об объекте класса, а не о самом классе. Исправил, но уже неактуально.